# Bash Terminal Ratio

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Good Day,
I have edited `.bashrc` file and add PS1 custom to it

```
# If id command returns zero, you got root access.

    if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ];
    then # you are root, set red colour prompt
      PS1="\e[01;91m#\e[m \e[01m\W\e[m \e[01;91m➜\e[m "
    else # normal
      PS1="\e[01;94m~\e[m \e[01m\W\e[m \e[01;94m➜\e[m "
    fi
```

The problem is when I try to type long command it repeated in same line without completing the whole line.
Also, when I click up arrow button it missed up and shows half of previous command.
Even the `stty` variables are correct (rows - cols)

Comment: See also [Using echo -e in PS1 causes line break issues in shell](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/367485) and a few others. It's a FAQ here.

Comment: Also in [this bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053)